# SPSS: SPSSINC MERGE TABLES for Custom and Significant Tests Tables

Tags: merge, spss

Can I know how to merge two tables using SPSSINC MERGE TABLES by 
rows/columns?

I have tried using the following syntax but the output (orange cells) is not what I want 
:

```
SPSSINC MERGE TABLES MATCHLABEL="Column N %" ATTACH=ROWS 
MODE=MERGE 
/OPTIONS HIDE=YES APPENDTITLE=YES APPENDCAPTION=YES ADDLABELLEAF=YES 
HALIGN=RIGHT SEPARATOR="‎\n".
```

[image]

The format that I want is to (green cells):

1. Include (A) (B) ... after the third row (header)
2. Include the sig category in next row (instead of combining with Column N 
   %)

[image]

Is there any ways to do that? Thanks a lot!